# Advantages / Disadvantages to keep unused network adapters DISABLED

Tags: networking

OS is Windows 7 - 64 bit.

On my laptop, I keep the wireless adapter enabled (almost ALWAYS in use). All others - like ethernet, VPN, hamachi, virtualbox - I keep disabled, and manually enable as needed.

Are there any system resources or security advantages to my approach VS. just keeping all the adapters permanently enabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very minor performance boost to disabling the unused ones. There is no real advantage to leaving them all on other then convenience and only minor benefits to disabling them.

Personally, I leave them enabled since it really doesn't make too much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage I can think of would be in keeping the Wireless adapter from connecting and acquiring an IP address on the same network where you are connected via a wire.

Other than that I cannot imagine any other significant advantages to doing this.